# String erase function causing heap corruption

Tags: c++, string, memory, copy, heap-corruption

Hello I'm working on my string class and I wanted to add an erase function. So I figured I go with the strategy of copying the memory before the start index, then copy the memory after the length + start index. This would just copy over the data outside of the part you want to delete.

Here is my code right now.

```
//size is the current size of the string not including the null terminator character
//data is the character array of data

    void erase(const size_t start, const size_t length) {
            if (start + length <= size) {
                size_t tempsize = start + length;
                char* temp = new char[size + 1 - length];
                
                //copy before start
                if(start > 0)
                    memcpy(temp, data, start);

                //copy after start (including null terminator character)
                memcpy(temp + start, data + start + length, size + 1 - length - start);

                delete[] data;

                data = temp;
                data[size] = '\0';
                size = tempsize;
            }
    }
```

It works completely fine by getting rid of the amount of characters that you want, but it throws a heap corruption error when I delete the string.

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:c++] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it stopped throw the exception, here's the current code if you want it.

```
void erase(const size_t& start, size_t length) {
            if (start >= size) {
                return;
            }

            if (start + length > size) {
                length = size - start;
            }

            char* temp = new char[size + 1 - length];

            //copy before start
            if (start > 0)
                memcpy(temp, data, start);

            //copy after start (including null terminator character)
            memcpy(temp + start, data + start + length, size + 1 - length - start);

            delete[] data;

            data = temp;
            size = size - length;

        }
```